# Is there any solution to left the cell empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a sheet along with this question,the formula used in column E2 is : if(and(d2>=0,d2<=2),5. So when the column is blank it  gives the value 5 My query is can we left the "E" column blank when there is no value in "D". ??? 5 must displayed only if there score between 0 & 2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XpdXcWDReB8TGvZ6ocALAilVPLDKzZXvd90YhNos0Io/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Iker. I've added a sheet with two approaches.

If you want to drag the formula, just set an initial IF that rules out blanks like this:

```
=if(D2="","",if(and(D2>=0,D2<=2),5,if(and(D2>=3,D2<=4),0)))
```

I placed this into my sheet, E2, and dragged down as you were doing.

However, this is a great example of where array formulas are handy. An array formula can "run" your whole column from just one cell. I placed the following array formula into cell I1 of my sheet:

```
=ArrayFormula({"POINT";IF(H2:H="","",IF((H2:H>=0)*(H2:H<=2),5,IF((H2:H>=3)*(H2:H<=4),0,"")))})
```

First, keep in mind that array formulas must have unused space below them in order to fill in results. If you type anything manually below an array formula, inside the range it is trying to work on, you'll get an error. If you do want to put other data below an array formula, just limit the range in the array formula (e.g., change every H2:H to H2:H6 or whatever the end of that data range might be).

ArrayFormula() tells Google Sheets to apply this formula to the entire range in the formula. Since the range in the formula is H2:H, every cell in I2:I will be "reserved" by this array formula.

The curly brackets {} allow us to build another custom array inside the first array.

Since I want a header in I1, I put that header name first in the curly brackets. The semicolon tells the array to put the next part *underneath*.

The next part may look strange, but it's basically the same as your original formula, *except* that AND(), OR(), etc., don't work inside arrays. So the logical operators inside arrays are different. In this case, an asterisk * means AND.

The same conditions from your original formula are used here. And if it meets none of those criteria (for instance, if someone entered -1 or 7 or M somewhere in Column H, the last part of the last IF would just assign a blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an added `IF` to your formula

```
=IF(D2="","", if(and(D2>=0,D2<=2),5,if(and(D2>=3,D2<=4),0)))
```

[image]